# Run wkhtmltopdf on CentOS 5.5 32bit

Tags: 32-bit, centos5, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to run wkhtmltopdf on CentOS 5.5 32bit version, I'm running that software on a VPS. Somehow I cannot execute the binary, this is what I get:

```
-bash-3.2# ./wkhtmltopdf-i386 http://www.google.nl/ test.pdf
Segmentation fault
```

I haven't got a clue to what the problem might be, the file has the proper owner and it's permissions are 777. The only thing I can think of making this problem go away is installing the X11 packages on my VPS, I'm not sure if that will solve the problem though.

Edit: Installed the X11 packages and I'm still getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've worked it out, apparently when extracting the wkhtmltopdf-i386 file on Windows and then transferring it via FTP it corrupts the file, resulting in the Segmentation fault error. The problem was solved using wget and downloading+extracting the file on the server.

Comment: Tip: You should post this as a answer and accept it.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I've just done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out, apparently when extracting the wkhtmltopdf-i386 file on Windows and then transferring it via FTP it corrupts the file, resulting in the Segmentation fault error. The problem was solved using wget and downloading+extracting the file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me and got it fixed, same thing you did.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=289