# wkhtmltopdf segfaults

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to put wkhtmltopdf onto a virtualbox'ed ubuntu 12.04 64bit server. So far no luck.
The package from the repositories wants to have xserver running and the static version:

```
wkhtmltopdf google.com tesss.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method               ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used===] Page 1 of 1
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used
Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas how could I approach this?

Comment: Would this help you run it without x: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12483745/694325 ? Installing  openSSL might help with the https issues (so I hear, haven't tested).

Comment: Maybe, but since I am not using the wkhtmltopdf directly (using the php integration library) I might need to change the library to use the calling method described above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986632/run-wkhtmltopdf-on-centos-5-5-32bit had similar problem and it was related to transfer errors, but I am using wget and extractin on the server. The same error appears on CentOS 5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=730

Basically, it got fixed around a year ago, but has still not been released. What a mess :(

Try using [0.10.0_rc2 version](http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64.tar.bz2) instead, which worked perfectly for me

Comment: Yeah, I used the rc2 version too.

Comment: You're correct, but after a quick inspection it looks like 0.10.0_rc2 doesn't do kerning where 0.11.0_rc1 does. Very disappointing.

Comment: Where can I find this version source, I've tried with the 0.9.9 but seems not to support QT?

Comment: This is still the best solution I found. About 10 months later.

Answer (score 6):

The QPixmap errors are not causing the segmentation fault. In fact, adding the `--disable-javascript` option solves the issue. You will still get the warnings but the PDF is generated correctly. HTH.

Comment: This fixed my issue, CentOS 6, Apache 2.22, PHP 5.4, wkhtmltopdf binary from wkhtmltopdf.org 0.12.1 (with patched Qt). Conversion worked fine with `sudo -u apache wkhtmltopdf ...` but Segfaulted when exec() from PHP. With --disable-javascript works there too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (segfault) and found out I had a ulimit -v (virtual memory) limit set when executing wkhtmltopdf from apache. Everything was running fine from command line when using the same command.

I was able to fit it by prepending the command with ulimit like this: "ulimit -v 1073741824; wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter ...."

Answer (score 1):

#### Upgrade to 0.12.6.

I know this is an old issue but for those still running into this, try upgrading to the latest version (0.12.6 at the time of writing). A lot of these issues have been fixed in the last few releases.

After that, try adjusting your `ulimit` on your machine as others have mentioned.

Then finally, if you are showing the current and total pages in your header or footer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66369004/293280) for a good tip and solution.

Answer (score 0):

binary used: wkhtmltopdf 0.11.0 rc1 linux i386

I have seen the segmentation faults when converting pages having Google Maps JS API embedded. In those cases an output file having 0 byte size was generated. Did not find any solution to get this version running by different command line arguments to wkhtmltopdf.

Finally switched to [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) in order to prevent the heavy JS work, which seems to cause the problem. This just embeds the map as a static image, which looks quite well when printing if you supply scale=2 as an option.